# VM Exception while processing transaction: revert TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED when running manipulatePrice.js test for bot.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, solidity, ganache

I am using the code from Dapp Unversity's trading bot masterclass to try to create a bot that will scan cryptocurrency decentralized exchanges for price differences in token pairs and then execute a smart contract to use a flash loan to profit off of this. When testing, I am able to see run a ganache-cli node and run my scanning bot to listen for swap opportunities on ganache. There is a script designed to create a swap opportunity by swapping a large amount of SHIB for WETH on the test net to see if the smart contract will deploy and execute when a swap opportunity is detected by the bot. However, running this script yields the error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Also, in the ganache-cli terminal, I get:

> Runtime Error: revert
> Revert reason: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Here are the commands I run to get to the points above:
First, I successfully run `ganache-cli -f wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<Your-App-Key> -u 0x0e5069514a3dd613350bab01b58fd850058e5ca4 -p 7545` with my app key.
Then, I successfully run `node bot.js` in another terminal to scan for swap opportunities on ganache. Finally, I run `node scripts\manipulatePrice.JS` which outputs "Beginnig Swap... Input token: SHIB Output token: WETH" before outputting the above error.

I have tried using `node --trace-warnings` to show where the warning was created, but was led nowhere helpful. I am wondering if it has something to do with the Runtime Error: revert message? Below is the code for the manipulatePrice.js script I am trying to run to test my bot. I can attach more code if need be, but don't want to post too much. If anyone has insight as to what or where the issue might be, I would greatly appreciate it!!

```
require("dotenv").config();

const Web3 = require('web3')
const {
    ChainId,
    Token,
    WETH
} = require("@uniswap/sdk")
const IUniswapV2Router02 = require('@uniswap/v2-periphery/build/IUniswapV2Router02.json')
const IUniswapV2Factory = require("@uniswap/v2-core/build/IUniswapV2Factory.json")
const IERC20 = require('@openzeppelin/contracts/build/contracts/ERC20.json')

// -- SETUP NETWORK & WEB3 -- //

const chainId = ChainId.MAINNET
const web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:7545')

// -- IMPORT HELPER FUNCTIONS -- //

const { getPairContract, calculatePrice } = require('../helpers/helpers')

// -- IMPORT & SETUP UNISWAP/SUSHISWAP CONTRACTS -- //

const config = require('../config.json')
const uFactory = new web3.eth.Contract(IUniswapV2Factory.abi, config.UNISWAP.FACTORY_ADDRESS) // UNISWAP FACTORY CONTRACT
const sFactory = new web3.eth.Contract(IUniswapV2Factory.abi, config.SUSHISWAP.FACTORY_ADDRESS) // SUSHISWAP FACTORY CONTRACT
const uRouter = new web3.eth.Contract(IUniswapV2Router02.abi, config.UNISWAP.V2_ROUTER_02_ADDRESS) // UNISWAP ROUTER CONTRACT
const sRouter = new web3.eth.Contract(IUniswapV2Router02.abi, config.SUSHISWAP.V2_ROUTER_02_ADDRESS) // UNISWAP ROUTER CONTRACT

// -- CONFIGURE VALUES HERE -- //

const V2_FACTORY_TO_USE = uFactory
const V2_ROUTER_TO_USE = uRouter

const UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT = '0x0e5069514a3Dd613350BAB01B58FD850058E5ca4' // SHIB Unlocked Account
const ERC20_ADDRESS = process.env.ARB_AGAINST
const AMOUNT = '40500000000000' // 40,500,000,000,000 SHIB -- Tokens will automatically be converted to wei
const GAS = 450000

// -- SETUP ERC20 CONTRACT & TOKEN -- //

const ERC20_CONTRACT = new web3.eth.Contract(IERC20.abi, ERC20_ADDRESS)
const WETH_CONTRACT = new web3.eth.Contract(IERC20.abi, WETH[chainId].address)

// -- MAIN SCRIPT -- //

const main = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    const account = accounts[1] // This will be the account to recieve WETH after we perform the swap to manipulate price

    const pairContract = await getPairContract(V2_FACTORY_TO_USE, ERC20_ADDRESS, WETH[chainId].address)
    const token = new Token(
        ChainId.MAINNET,
        ERC20_ADDRESS,
        18,
        await ERC20_CONTRACT.methods.symbol().call(),
        await ERC20_CONTRACT.methods.name().call()
    )

    // Fetch price of SHIB/WETH before we execute the swap
    const priceBefore = await calculatePrice(pairContract)

    await manipulatePrice(token, account)

    // Fetch price of SHIB/WETH after the swap
    const priceAfter = await calculatePrice(pairContract)

    const data = {
        'Price Before': `1 ${WETH[chainId].symbol} = ${Number(priceBefore).toFixed(0)} ${token.symbol}`,
        'Price After': `1 ${WETH[chainId].symbol} = ${Number(priceAfter).toFixed(0)} ${token.symbol}`,
    }

    console.table(data)

    let balance = await WETH_CONTRACT.methods.balanceOf(account).call()
    balance = web3.utils.fromWei(balance.toString(), 'ether')

    console.log(`\nBalance in reciever account: ${balance} WETH\n`)
}

main()

// 

async function manipulatePrice(token, account) {
    console.log(`\nBeginning Swap...\n`)

    console.log(`Input Token: ${token.symbol}`)
    console.log(`Output Token: ${WETH[chainId].symbol}\n`)

    const amountIn = new web3.utils.BN(
        web3.utils.toWei(AMOUNT, 'ether')
    )

    const path = [token.address, WETH[chainId].address]
    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20 // 20 minutes

    await ERC20_CONTRACT.methods.approve(V2_ROUTER_TO_USE._address, amountIn).send({ from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT })
    const receipt = await V2_ROUTER_TO_USE.methods.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, 0, path, account, deadline).send({ from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT, gas: GAS });

    console.log(`Swap Complete!\n`)

    return receipt
}
```

Comment: By looking at the error the require `TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED` reverts. Can you try to locate that require and paste the source code?

Comment: @NiccolòFant Thanks for the tip, I'll try and locate that source code

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue for the same bot myself and I found the solution. Instead of using `.send` you should use `.sendSignedTransaction` and sign it yourself with the correct parameters. **BUT** if you are sending from an unlocked account, then use ethers.js to get a signer without knowing the private key!

So, you should replace

```
await ERC20_CONTRACT.methods.approve(V2_ROUTER_TO_USE._address, amountIn).send({ from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT })
const receipt = await V2_ROUTER_TO_USE.methods.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, 0, path, account, deadline).send({ from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT, gas: GAS });
```

With this ethers.js alternative

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers")
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545")
const signer = provider.getSigner(UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT)
console.log(provider.chainId)

/*
    Define the above code at the top,
    Then put the rest of your code here, 
    Then use this for the ethers transaction
*/

const approvalReceiptEthers = await signer.sendTransaction({
    from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT,
    to: ERC20_CONTRACT._address,
    data: ERC20_CONTRACT.methods.approve(V2_ROUTER_TO_USE._address, web3.utils.fromWei(amountIn).toString()).encodeABI(),
    gasLimit: GAS
})

/*
 * Verify that your unlocked account is allowed to use the funds
*/
var allowance = await ERC20_CONTRACT.methods.allowance(UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT, V2_ROUTER_TO_USE._address).call()
console.log("ALLOWANCE:\t\t", web3.utils.fromWei(allowance).toString(), 'ether')
console.log("ATTEMPTED AMOUNT:\t", web3.utils.fromWei(amountIn).toString(), 'ether')


const swapReceiptEthers = await signer.sendTransaction({
    from: UNLOCKED_ACCOUNT,
    to: V2_ROUTER_TO_USE._address,
    data: V2_ROUTER_TO_USE.methods.swapExactTokensForTokens(web3.utils.fromWei(amountIn).toString(), 0, path, account, deadline).encodeABI(),
    gasLimit: GAS
}).then(console.log)
```

**Note:** the following code, will only work provided that you signed the transaction with *THE SENDER'S PRIVATE KEY.* So, if you are sending a transaction on behalf of your own account, use this code (presumably for bot.js)

```
const approvalTransaction = {
    'from' : 'your account address here',
    'to' : ERC20_CONTRACT._address,
    'data' : ERC20_CONTRACT.methods.approve(V2_ROUTER_TO_USE._address, web3.utils.fromWei(amountIn).toString()).encodeABI(),
    'gas' : GAS
}
const transaction = {
    'from' : 'your account address here',
    'to' : V2_ROUTER_TO_USE._address,
    'data' : V2_ROUTER_TO_USE.methods.swapExactTokensForTokens(web3.utils.fromWei(amountIn).toString(), 0, path, account, deadline).encodeABI(),
    'gas' : GAS
    
}
const signedApprovalTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(approvalTransaction, process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ACCOUNT_KEY, )
const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ACCOUNT_KEY)

await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedApprovalTx.rawTransaction)
const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
```

**NOTE**: For those of you following the same Trading Bot masterclass, this same logic applies to the `bot.js` code as well when you execute your trade!.

**SUMMARY:** If you are sending a signed transaction using an unlocked account with ganache-cli, you will need to use ethers.js to sign the message without knowing the private key. Otherwise if you are sending a signed transaction on behalf of yourself, you can use Web3.js to sign the message with your own private